# Processing Payments from via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, payment-processing

I'm working to integrate the [Payment Request API](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/payments/) into my website. I want to support various payment methods and this API looks like what I need. However, while processing credit cards is demonstrated, this doesn't actually collect the money. Instead, it's a developer's responsibility to take the data collected via the Payment Request API and run it through a credit card processor. That's where all of this gets sticky.

Is there a payment processor that can be used with the Payment Request API? Everything I see relies on some sort of server-side generation of the form. Supposedly, this is due to PCI compliance. This would mean that any implementation using the Payment Request API would not be PCI compliant. Am I missing something here? Is there a credit card processor that works with the Payment Request API that is PCI compliant? If so, which one?

Comment: Who upvoted this? This is clearly off-topic.

Comment: Could you provide more context? What is your full stack? Saying `via javascript` these days doesn't define much in scope of your question

Comment: @KazRodgers - Node.js backend. I'm using the Payment Request API on the front end.

Comment: @JohnConde - How is this "off-topic"? It's an integration related question.

Comment: @user687554 are you on angular or react? jQuery? Or just straight up vanilla?

Comment: @KazRodgers straight up vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: This question is asking for a recommendation of processor which is always off-topic